# rclcpp no such file or directory

Tags: ros2

I keep getting no such file or directory. when i tried to add this to my source file #include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp". what I don't understand is VC says no such file but when I write some functions from this library it autocompletes them.

Here is the error.

Starting build...
fatal error: rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp: No such file or directory
1 | #include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Also here are cmake and .json files.

```
.json where I added library path.
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/ros/humble/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}


cmake file.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_cpp_pkg)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)


if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()



ament_package()


The source code.

#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"


    int main(int argc, char **argv){
    
        rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
        
        rclcpp::shutdown();
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you build failed as well? I notice you haven't add your .cpp file as a target and rclcpp is not link to it.

You could check [this example](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/foxy/demo_nodes_cpp_native/CMakeLists.txt), and replace your *.cpp file name with this.

Update: I paste the code here in case link not work.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(demo_nodes_cpp_native)

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp_components REQUIRED)
find_package(rmw REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rmw_fastrtps_cpp QUIET)

include_directories(include)

if(rmw_fastrtps_cpp_FOUND)
  add_library(talker_native SHARED
    src/talker.cpp)
  target_compile_definitions(talker_native
    PRIVATE "DEMO_NODES_CPP_NATIVE_BUILDING_DLL")
  ament_target_dependencies(talker_native
    "rclcpp"
    "std_msgs"
    "rclcpp_components"
    "rmw_fastrtps_cpp")
  rclcpp_components_register_node(talker_native PLUGIN "demo_nodes_cpp_native::Talker" EXECUTABLE talker)
  install(TARGETS
    talker_native
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

  if(BUILD_TESTING)
    find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
    ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()

    find_package(ament_cmake_pytest REQUIRED)
    find_package(launch_testing_ament_cmake REQUIRED)

    set(tutorial_executables "talker")

    set(DEMO_NODES_CPP_EXPECTED_OUTPUT "")
    foreach(executable ${tutorial_executables})
      list(APPEND DEMO_NODES_CPP_EXPECTED_OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/${executable}")
    endforeach()

    set(DEMO_NODES_CPP_EXECUTABLE "")
    foreach(executable ${tutorial_executables})
      list(APPEND DEMO_NODES_CPP_EXECUTABLE "$<TARGET_FILE:${executable}>")
    endforeach()

    string(REPLACE ";" "_" exe_list_underscore "${tutorial_executables}")
    configure_file(
      test/test_executables_tutorial.py.in
      test_${exe_list_underscore}.py.configured
      @ONLY
    )
    file(GENERATE
      OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_${exe_list_underscore}_$<CONFIG>.py"
      INPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_${exe_list_underscore}.py.configured"
    )

    add_launch_test(
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_${exe_list_underscore}_$<CONFIG>.py"
      TARGET test_tutorial_${exe_list_underscore}
      TIMEOUT 30
      ENV
      RCL_ASSERT_RMW_ID_MATCHES=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
      RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
    )
    foreach(executable ${tutorial_executables})
      set_property(
        TEST test_tutorial_${exe_list_underscore}
        APPEND PROPERTY DEPENDS ${executable})
    endforeach()
  endif()
endif()

ament_package()
```

I think from your CMakefile, you might forget to declare..

1. A executable target, e.g your .cpp file.
2. a library link to thes executable target.

Answer (score 0):

The include file sits in /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp
if you are using humble LTS for ubuntu